# Here Maps javascript api 3.1 and Internet Explorer support

Tags: here-api

Trying to get a map with pins to display in internet explorer which this page claims to support https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/overview.html but none of the examples in the developer documentation seem to run in IE 11

Table from url

```
+===============================+==============================+
|        Support Level          |           Browser            |
+===============================+==============================+
| Supported with optimizations: | Edge 17+                     |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                               | Firefox (latest)             |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                               | Google Chrome (latest)       |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                               | Apple Safari 11+             |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Legacy support:               | Internet Explorer 9, 10, 11  |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                               | iOS WebView                  |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Not supported:                | Opera                        |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                               |  Internet Explorer < 9       |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Here is an example map that won't load https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/maps/interactive-basemap

Does anyone have any working examples of the 3.1 api in IE?

Comment: Hi, Did you try to add the api key in place of window.apikey parameter in the script.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Yes I have set up an example here loading raster tiles:

View for IE: https://s.codepen.io/shanegerhardt/debug/xxKZPdg/yPAJjKPRRVmA

View with code: https://codepen.io/shanegerhardt/pen/xxKZPdg

Map loads fine in current browsers, but in IE it logs an error and prevents the tiles from being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have working map on legacy browsers, you need to include mapsjs-core-legacy.js package. 
See https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/overview.html#overview__modules

Also you need to set engineType parameter when creating map object:
`engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D`
See https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-options.html

Unfortunately the example you attached ([Interactive base map](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/maps/interactive-basemap)) as well as example [Change map style at runtime](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/maps/change-style-at-runtime) won't work on legacy browsers as they need WebGL rendering engine for vector rendering.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I've set up a code example here:
https://s.codepen.io/shanegerhardt/debug/xxKZPdg/yPAJjKPRRVmA (debug view for IE)

https://codepen.io/shanegerhardt/pen/xxKZPdg (full view)

I am loading the scripts in this order:

https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js

However IE logs this error from the mapsjs-core.js file: Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'

Comment: You are missing engineType parameter in Map options:

 engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D